# Are The Adventures of Pinocchio on-topic?

Tags: discussion

Are [The Adventures of Pinocchio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_Pinocchio) a fantasy and therefore on-topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is fantasy and therefore it is very much on topic. Ask away.

Wikipedia defines fantasy as:

> Fantasy is a genre of fiction that uses magic or other
>   supernatural elements as a main plot element, theme, or setting.
>   Many works within the genre take place in imaginary worlds where
>   magic and magical creatures are common.

The Adventures of Pinocchio checks out on all counts.

Comment: The Wikipedia page very clearly lists one of it's genres as fantasy and Google tells me it falls under Speculative Fiction and Fantasy Fiction so yes it is on topic.